# How do I load a chunk of javascript to be used with my action form in MoinMoin?

Tags: javascript, moinmoin

I've created a moin-moin action, and would like to add some javascript-y animations to it.

That means that my form would require some javascript libraries to be loaded.

How do I instruct moinmoin to load some (external) javascript libraries when it serves the form for my action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you did an action plugin, it has complete control over the output (http headers and body), so you can do whatever you want.

so, just create some html that loads your js and let your action emit it.

Comment: any chance you have an example which controls emitted headers?